# Create a .jar from a JavaFX file Maven with all java dependencies

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar

I am trying to compile a Jave project using maven into a single executable .jar but am recieveing one of two errors:

```
no main manifest attribute, in csci6461-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or one pertaining to JavaFX

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I need the file to be able to be ran directly by the user, what is the best way to approach this?

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.csci6461</groupId>
    <artifactId>csci6461</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CSCI6461</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codeartisans.javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codeartisans.javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-deployer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Skip the tests run. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Sources generation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.csci6461.ComputerSimulation</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have also tried using an Ant build but the latter of the two errors still persist.

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562250/1947796

Comment: Your approach is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823040/1155209).

Comment: @OmarAbdullwahhab That semi works but it refuses to run on Mac :/

Comment: What is "that" and what is "it"?

Comment: @mipa "that" is the solution he referenced  and "it" is the produced .jar as referenced in the question